# Unable to view the Available Qualifiers when creating a new XML file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, qualifiers

Hello I am new to Android Studio and Learning XML and JAVA through Big Nerd Ranch. For the most part things have been going smoothly, however I have encountered a new issue that I have not seen before. In a project I have been working on for a while I am suddenly unable to add qualifiers (in other programs on my computer I can still add them).
When I right click on my:
res directory -> new -> values resource file
I get a window that pops up only asking for me to enter the name of the file. This is an issue because the list of available qualifiers does not appear in this window, like normal, I do not know how to add a qualifier.
How does one add a qualifier when none show up in the file creation window?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a qualifier for an layout file for example. A new folder is created in the directory, with the name layout-qualifier. Take a look at this [Android Qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently and I realized that you have to specifically right click in the res folder, I was right clicking in the values folder

- Be sure to right click on the res folder (the root resource folder)
- Click New
- Click Android Resource File